# Restructure competition/race data

Tags: r

I have data from race competitions consisting of race time for a competitor, their position in the race, an independent variable `x` and raceid. I'm looking for a way to predict the outcome in a new race. Not just the winner, but the whole ranking. This is what the data looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(                                      
competitor = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "D"),     
time = c(54.2, 48.3, 49.1, 105.2, 116.2, 112.5, 117.3),
position = c(3,1,2,1,3,2,4),                           
x = c(4, 6, 2, 3, 7, 5, 2),                            
race = c("race1", "race1", "race1",                    
"race2", "race2", "race2", "race2")                    
)                                                      

#>   competitor  time position x  race
#> 1          A  54.2        3 4 race1
#> 2          B  48.3        1 6 race1
#> 3          C  49.1        2 2 race1
#> 4          A 105.2        1 3 race2
#> 5          B 116.2        3 7 race2
#> 6          C 112.5        2 5 race2
#> 7          D 117.3        4 2 race2
```

One idea I had was to restructure the data such that each competitor is "competing" against every other competitor. The data would then have to be restructured to look something like this for the first race:

```
df_wide <- data.frame(                       
competitor = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "B", "C"),
opponent = c("B", "A", "C", "A", "C", "B"),  
time = c(54.2,48.3, 54.2, 49.1, 48.3, 49.1), 
x = c(3,1,3,2,1,2),                          
win = c(0,1,0,1,1,0),                        
race = c("race1"))                           

#>   competitor opponent time x win  race
#> 1          A        B 54.2 3   0 race1
#> 2          B        A 48.3 1   1 race1
#> 3          A        C 54.2 3   0 race1
#> 4          C        A 49.1 2   1 race1
#> 5          B        C 48.3 1   1 race1
#> 6          C        B 49.1 2   0 race1
```

Then I suppose I could model the probability that A would win over B in a new race and thus predict position.

Does anyone know of a convenient way to restructure the data like this?

Comment: It doesn't look like the `x` variable in the example result is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question.

Unless I'm overcomplicating things, I believe the key to all this is using `outer` with `<` as the function. For example, the positions in the first race were:

```
pos <- c("A" = 3, "B" = 1, "C" = 2)
```

We can get a matrix of all possible win/loss comparisons like this:

```
(res <- outer(pos, pos, `<`))
#>       A     B     C
#> A FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> B  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#> C  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

We can then turn this into a suitable dataframe using `gather` and some other tricks. But in the end this has to be done for each race, and then the whole thing put back together and merged with the original dataframe. So we'll need a define a function which does the work. Here it is:

```
library(tidyverse)
all_pairs <- function(df) {
  pmat <- outer(df$position, df$position, `<`)
  rownames(pmat) <- colnames(pmat) <- df$competitor
  as.data.frame(pmat) %>% 
    rownames_to_column(var = "competitor") %>% 
    gather(opponent, win, -competitor) %>% 
    mutate(win=as.integer(win)) %>% 
    filter(competitor != opponent)
}
```

Let's try it out on the first race:

```
all_pairs(df[1:3,])
#>   competitor opponent win
#> 1          B        A   1
#> 2          C        A   1
#> 3          A        B   0
#> 4          C        B   0
#> 5          A        C   0
#> 6          B        C   1
```

I decided to use `split` and `lapply`. The `bind_rows` function has a nice way to recover the `race` variable. Here's the final answer:

```
left_join(df,
          bind_rows(lapply(split(df, factor(df$race)), all_pairs), .id = "race")) %>% 
  select(competitor, opponent, time, x, win, race)
#> Joining, by = c("competitor", "race")
#> # A tibble: 18 x 6
#>    competitor opponent  time     x   win race 
#>    <chr>      <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <int> <chr>
#>  1 A          B         54.2    4.     0 race1
#>  2 A          C         54.2    4.     0 race1
#>  3 B          A         48.3    6.     1 race1
#>  4 B          C         48.3    6.     1 race1
#>  5 C          A         49.1    2.     1 race1
#>  6 C          B         49.1    2.     0 race1
#>  7 A          B        105.     3.     1 race2
#>  8 A          C        105.     3.     1 race2
#>  9 A          D        105.     3.     1 race2
#> 10 B          A        116.     7.     0 race2
#> 11 B          C        116.     7.     0 race2
#> 12 B          D        116.     7.     1 race2
#> 13 C          A        112.     5.     0 race2
#> 14 C          B        112.     5.     1 race2
#> 15 C          D        112.     5.     1 race2
#> 16 D          A        117.     2.     0 race2
#> 17 D          B        117.     2.     0 race2
#> 18 D          C        117.     2.     0 race2
```

Comment: Ah, great. Guess it was outer I was looking for. This looks very neat. Thanks! Now, I'll just need to model this in a convienent way.